# Selecting specific IIS website using powershell

Tags: powershell, conditional-statements

I currently have several websites running under IIS. For ease lets call them `site1`, `site2`, and `site3`

My powershell script accepts a parameter from the user of which number site to work with. I am attempting to turn off site3 with simply the parameter `3`

I thought it would be something along the lines of

```
stop-website | where-object {$_.name -like "*3*"}
```

this line is executed, but brought to a prompt for "name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Name property seems to accept wildcards (although help states otherwise) so you should be able to stop it with this:

```
Stop-Website -Name *3*
```